# PrintDocument and Scrollviewer

Tags: silverlight, printing

I'm printing a large screen (tall) by pieces with the help of a `ScrollViewer`.
In the `PrintPage` handler I scroll down the `ScrollViewer` and then set the `PageVisual` to `ScrollViewer` instance. When the SV is at bottom then I set the `HasMorePages` property to false.
My problem is that this is working fine **on condition** that I prompt the user with a MessageBox between each page, otherwise the SV doesn't scroll except at the end of printing process.

I tried to do the scroll on the UI thread but no luck :

```
void Print_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // DefPage contains properties of the printed page
    DefPage defPage = _enumeratorPages.Current;
    e.HasMorePages = _enumeratorPages.MoveNext();
    ScrollViewerVertical.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate {
        ScrollViewerVertical.ScrollToVerticalOffset(defPage.OffsetY);
    });
    e.PageVisual = ScrollViewerVertical;
}
```

And if I use a `ManualResetEvent` with `WaitOne` to wait for the UI thread to update the scroll, my browser freeze...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to `ScrollViewerVertical.UpdateLayout()` solved the problem